# image display under menu bar on hover

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a menu with an image associated with every option.
I want that image to be hidden and shown only on mouse hover on the particular option.
Plus, I want the image to be half covered by the menu bar so it will show just its bottom half. Any idea of how to do it???

I've tried something like

HTML:

```
<div id="menu_bar">
     <a href="javascript:change(0)"> text <img src="image"> </a>
     <a href="javascript:change(1)"> text <img src="image"> </a>
     <a href="javascript:change(2)"> text <img src="image"> </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a>img { display: none; }
a:hover>img { display: block; }
```

but it's not even near of what i want to accomplish

Comment: Share some source code of what you have built so far.

Answer (score 0):

The html:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
     <li id="el-1"><span class="text">Item</span><img src="item-1.png" alt="" /></li>
     <li id="el-2"><span class="text">Item</span><img src="item-1.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

The Css

```
<style>
.main-menu li > span.text {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    background:white;
}
.main-menu li {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.main-menu li > img {
    display:none;
}
.main-menu li#el-1:hover > img {
    display:block;
    margin-top:-20%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: nice try but it shows all the images if there's more than one option in the menu