# overlapping divs on images

Tags: html, css

Here's what I would like to accomplish:

```
 _____________________________________________________________________________
|    option             option               option            option         |
|_____________________________________________________________________________|
  |  image  |         |  image  |          |  image  |       |  image  |
  |_________|         |_________|          |_________|       |_________|
```

in  a menu bar with only options and not buttons. Plus the images are shown just for the bottom half. I've tried this:

HTML

```
<div class="m_img"> <img src="image1.png" width="60px" height="30px"> </div>
<div class="m_img"> <img src="image2.png" width="60px" height="30px"> </div>
<div class="m_img"> <img src="image3.png" width="60px" height="30px"> </div>
<div class="m_img"> <img src="image4.png" width="60px" height="30px"> </div>
<div id="menu_bar" class="centered">
    <a class="m_button" href="javascript:change(0)"> text0 </a>
    <a class="m_button" href="javascript:change(1)"> text1 </a>
    <a class="m_button" href="javascript:change(2)"> text2 </a>
    <a class="m_button" href="javascript:change(3)"> text3 </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.m_img {
     float: left;
     width: 250px;
     z-index: 1;
}
.m_button {
     float: left;
     width: 250px;
     font-size: 110%;
     z-index: 2;
}
```

but the menu bar goes down and does not overlap the images. Any idea of how I can set it up?

Comment: A possible duplicate of [image display under menu bar on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424028/image-display-under-menu-bar-on-hover). On the assumption this question is trying to solve the same problem as your *other* question, please delete this one, and edit the additional information into *that* question.

Comment: You can set a z-index on the div `menu_bar` too?

Comment: no David Thomas i've solved that problem (the image displaying), now i'm trying to focus on the look. :)

Comment: If your other question is solved then it should be marked accepted.

Comment: I don't see what your talking about. Please create an example fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4yC7H/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div style="width:400px; background-color: red; font-size:1em; height:1em">
    <span class="menup option">option1</span>
    <span class="menup option">option2</span>
    <div style="z-index: -1; width: 100%; position:relative; top:-0.5em;">
        <span class="menup">menu1</span>
        <span class="menup">menu2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menup { background-color: blue; width: 6em; display: inline-block; margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em; }
.option { background-color: green; }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mK4bJ/1/

If you have comments, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Please refrain from using inline styles. I find them quite annoying.

Comment: it looks like what i was looking for editing it a bit from jsfiddle. I'll try it during the afternoon and see if it works really well

Comment: One gets sick of continuously editing people's post. It's better to tell them and hopefully they'll learn from it.